# java 8 - print a map sorted by key

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am printing a map sorted by key with an intermediate object LinkedHashMap as follows;

```
 LinkedHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> sortedMap = wcMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));

 sortedMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(String.format("%s ==>> %d",k, v.get())));
```

How can I print it directly from the stream before collecting?

Comment: What do u mean directly? Chain `forEach`?

Comment: Before collecting.

Comment: There's `peek` for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you are not interested in the collected `LinkedHashMap`:

```
wcMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.println(String.format("%s ==>> %d", e.getKey(), e.getValue().get()));
```

Or even better:

```
wcMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .map(e -> String.format("%s ==>> %d", e.getKey(), e.getValue().get()))
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

In case you still want the resulting `LinkedHashMap`, use `peek()`:

```
wcMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .peek(e -> System.out.println(String.format("%s ==>> %d", e.getKey(), e.getValue().get())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* utilise `forEach` before collecting because that would *consume* the stream and that means you can no longer collect.

You can either use the [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) intermediate operation to perform a certain action (mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline) and then `collect`  or `collect` and then apply `forEach` as you've done.

Example with `peek`:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> sortedMap = wcMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .peek(e -> System.out.println(String.format("%s ==>> %d", e.getKey(), e.getValue().get())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Also, if you're only interested in printing the data then there is no need to dump the result into a `Map` instance as it's unnecessary and can be avoided. Thus, you can just chain a `forEach` terminal operation after the `sorted` operation and print the data.